# Using Message Bus to trigger events based on custom property changes

Tags: scripting

following Blenders documentation from the following link:

https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.msgbus.html

I am trying to adapt the example to add a subscription to a custom property as follow:

```
import bpy
    
    
def notification_handler(*args):
    # This will print:
    # Something changed! (1, 2, 3)
    print("Something changed!", args)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    subscription_owner = bpy.types.Collection
    subscribe_to = bpy.context.scene['myproperty']
    
    print(subscribe_to)
    bpy.msgbus.subscribe_rna(
        key=subscribe_to,
        owner=subscription_owner,
        args=("example argument",),
        notify=notification_handler,
        options=set(["PERSISTENT"])
    )
```

Then, in the python console, I execute the following command:

```
bpy.context.scene['myproperty'] = "new value"
```

And I see that the value changes in the UI but there is nothing printed in the console (I launch Blender from the CLI).

I suspect that the values of `subcription_owner` and `subscribe_to` are not totally correct, but I don't know how to continue.

Anyone knows how to do it?

Comment: I tried with the object and a few of more options, but the problem is that I don't even see the point of that owner parameter. What is that for? I have the feeling that there are much more behind `subscribe_rna` that is not well documented.

Comment: after testing a bit i would say: maybe a bug in Blender. With objects everything is fine, but the scene properties change won't call the handler. So as workaround - just save it in an object rather than in scene.

Comment: Thanks for testing, Chris. I am trying different approaches also, like storing the data in an instance of `bpy.props.CollectionProperty`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the documentation :

> Some properties are converted to Python objects when you retrieve
> them. This needs to be avoided in order to create the subscription, by
> using datablock.path_resolve("property_name", False):
>
> subscribe_to = bpy.context.object.path_resolve("name", False)

The callback doesn't work because in `subscribe_to = bpy.context.scene['myproperty']`, the right part of the statement evaluates to a python object (eg `float` if your property is a `FloatProperty`), and from this point there is no tie to the Blender API to get value updates to the msgbus.

[image]

With `path_resolve` you're actually pointing to the API property, which has an available callback .

[image]

It seems you do have to register `my_property` as a global `bpy.types.Scene` property if you want the callback to fire. I didn't find a way to make it work for regular custom props.

Your code then becomes :

```
import bpy
    
    
def notification_handler(*args):
    # This will print:
    # Something changed! (1, 2, 3)
    print("Something changed!", args)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":        
    subscription_owner = bpy.types.Collection

    bpy.types.Scene.my_property = bpy.props.FloatProperty()
    subscribe_to = bpy.context.scene.path_resolve("my_property", False)
    
    print(subscribe_to)
    bpy.msgbus.subscribe_rna(
        key=subscribe_to,
        owner=subscription_owner,
        args=("example argument",),
        notify=notification_handler,
        options=set(["PERSISTENT"])
    )
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I followed your recommendation and I made it work. However, it only triggers the event from the UI, not from the Python console. I am not sure if I will encounter problems later because of that. The whole intention of that is to subscribe a property to a system socket and be able to trigger them from a different process ... wish me luck :D

Comment: It should be triggered with the Python API, but I don't know if it will work with an entirely different process :) good luck

Comment: I don't want to extend the question, but as you may now more about the `bpy.props` library. Is there any way to instantiate a different class (ie. defined in an imported module)?

Comment: If having to define via `bpy.props` probably leads to question, why not then  use a property `update` callback, or getter / setter?  The owner is arbitrary and often see `owner = object()`  See no advantage in using  a member  `bpy.types`

Comment: @batFINGER Agreed, it seems way more straightforward to use props get/set/update methods for this. Héctor Valverde Pareja : Might be worth digging around https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html or try to define more the end goal

Comment: Ok. To be honest, I think this particular question has been successfully answered here. Thanks to you, I managed to trigger the event after a value update. Now my problem may be more complex so I will ask other questions. I will link my next one here if you are interested. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Anyway, I am not sure if I understand you, but probably using a property callback is not possible for me, because the value of the property I want to catch is a socket. I am trying to listen to what is happening in a parallel process in order to trigger a notification with the process is done. I will probably explain more details in a separate question