# Do something when an enumerator is changed

Tags: python, scripting, properties

When I choose an option for one of my enumators in my script, I can tell from the "info" space that there is a command:

bpy.context.scene.extra.[name of enumerator] = '[option]'

I want to have the script do something whenever this command happens, or just whenever the enumerator is changed in general, but I don't know how.

Comment: Try to use Message Bus: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.msgbus.html

Comment: Well right now I just have: owner = bpy.types.Scene.extra
    key = bpy.context.scene.extra.Enumerator_name
    bpy.msgbus.subscribe_rna(key=key, owner=owner, args=(), notify=doSomething,). To be honest I have no idea what I'm doing, but it did work when I filled in owner = object() and key = bpy.context.object.location, like they did on the link that you sent. @XY

Comment: Update: I managed to make it work! I did a little bit more research and thanks to this helpful q&a: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/224010/using-message-bus-to-trigger-events-based-on-custom-property-changes I managed to make it work: Here is the final result: owner = bpy.types.Scene.extra
    key = bpy.context.scene.path_resolve("extra.Enumerator_name", False)
    bpy.msgbus.subscribe_rna(key=key, owner=owner, args=(), notify=doSomething,)

Comment: If you found an answer, please answer yourself, it will help other people with similar problems in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out how to do it with a "Message Bus". I put the following script under `def register():`:

```
def register():
    owner = bpy.types.Scene.extra
    key = bpy.context.scene.path_resolve("extra.Enumerator_name", False)
    bpy.msgbus.subscribe_rna(key=key, owner=owner, args=(), notify=doSomething,)
```

What the code does is it effects `doSomething` whenever the enumerator is changed. To set up `doSomething`, you just do the following: type "`def doSomething(*args):`" somewhere in your script and then put whatever it is you want to happen after that. Here are the sources I used in case you want to check it out: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.msgbus.html and [Using Message Bus to trigger events based on custom property changes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/224010/using-message-bus-to-trigger-events-based-on-custom-property-changes)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use [Update](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html#update-example)? It seems to be very easy:

```
import bpy

def update_func(self, context):
    print("Updated: ", self.testprop)

bpy.types.Scene.testprop = bpy.props.FloatProperty(update=update_func)

bpy.context.scene.testprop = 11.0
```